# Problem downloading a game

Tags: google-play-store, clash-of-clans, samsung-galaxy-core-2

I'm trying to download Clash of Clans from Google Play, as I always did. My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Core 2, and the Android version is 4.4.2.

The download starts but when it is done appears a message like this:

> Application cannot be installed in the default install location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you set default install location to SD card and clash of clans can not be installed on SD Cards , change the default path for installing apps in settings and try again .

Update 1 : 
May be you have not enough disk space in Internal Storage . Try to remove some apps and install again . sometimes a restart after clean up is necessary .

Comment: I have not SD card, and neither can choose the default path for installing apps.